# Model for simple production chain economy

Tags: mathematical-economics, production-function

Given a simplistic economical model with a finite number of possible resources, and a set of machines that can be produced (with a cost) that that take some or none input, and give some output per time-division, I wish to find the time-optimal production chain for a goal. What sources of information and fields of production management and economics could I use to find a solution? Can the solution be found with any other method rather than a deep search of a Markov-decision chain?